# VBA Macro to Create Closed Shape in AutoCAD 2021

Tags: vba, debugging, runtime, autocad, invalid-argument

```vb
Sub CreateClosedShape()
    Dim Myapp As Object
    Dim myDwg As AcadDocument
    Dim autocadPath As String
    autocadPath = "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2021\acad.exe"
    
   
    'Attempt to get the running instance of AutoCAD
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Myapp = GetObject(, "Autocad.Application")
    On Error GoTo errorhandler:
    
 errorhandler:
    
    'If AutoCAD is not running, create a new instance
    If Myapp Is Nothing Then
        Set Myapp = CreateObject("Autocad.Application")
    End If
    
    ' Set the path to the AutoCAD executable
    'Myapp.Application.Path = autocadPath
    Myapp.Visible = True
    
    
Set myDwg = Myapp.ActiveDocument
   

     ' Assuming your Excel data is in Sheet1, starting from cell A1
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        
        ' Assuming your data consists of X and Y coordinates in columns A and B
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
        ' Check if there are enough points to create a closed shape
        If lastRow < 2 Then
            MsgBox "Insufficient data to create a closed shape.", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        ' Get the vertices as a list
        Dim verticesList() As Double
        ReDim verticesList(0 To lastRow * 2 - 1)
        
        Dim i As Long
        Dim j As Long
        j = -1
       
        For i = 1 To lastRow
            j = j + 1
       verticesList(j) = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
       j = j + 1
       verticesList(j) = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
        Next i
        
        
        ' Create a polyline to represent the closed shape
        Dim polylineObj As IAcadLWPolyline
        Set polylineObj = myDwg.ModelSpace.AddLightWeightPolyline(verticesList)
        
        Dim offsetDistance As Double
        offsetDistance1 = 0.15  ' You can change this value
        offsetDistance2 = 0.075  ' You can change this value
    
    ' Create an offset of the polyline
        Dim offsetPolylineObj1 As IAcadLWPolyline
        Dim offsetPolylineObj2 As IAcadLWPolyline
        
        Set offsetPolylineObj1 = 
          myDwg.ModelSpace.AddLightWeightPolyline(polylineObj.Offset(offsetDistance1))
        Set offsetPolylineObj2 = 
          myDwg.ModelSpace.AddLightWeightPolyline(offsetPolylineObj1.Offset(offsetDistance2))
        
        MsgBox "Closed shape created successfully!", vbInformation
    End Sub
```

```
    Set offsetPolylineObj1 = 
     myDwg.ModelSpace.AddLightWeightPolyline(polylineObj.Offset(offsetDistance1))
        Set offsetPolylineObj2 = 
     myDwg.ModelSpace.AddLightWeightPolyline(offsetPolylineObj1.Offset(offsetDistance2))
```

i getting error for above two line like invalid argument runtime error 5

Answer (score 0):

[AddPolyline Method](https://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2016/ENU/?guid=GUID-ED02917C-D1D6-46B8-95C6-736163C31362) must have argument as Variant Type (array of doubles)!

```
polylineObj.Offset(offsetDistance1)
```

Please read more about [Offset Method](https://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2016/ENU/?guid=GUID-50EF273A-7552-4D6B-8523-BB956334D08A).
This code works at my side

```
    Sub CreateClosedShape()
    Dim Myapp As Object
    Dim myDwg As AcadDocument
 
    'Attempt to get the running instance of AutoCAD
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Myapp = GetObject(, "Autocad.Application")
    On Error GoTo errorhandler:
    
errorhandler:
    
    'If AutoCAD is not running, create a new instance
    If Myapp Is Nothing Then
        Set Myapp = CreateObject("Autocad.Application")
    End If
  
    ' Set the path to the AutoCAD executable
    'Myapp.Application.Path = autocadPath
    Myapp.Visible = True
    
Set myDwg = Myapp.ActiveDocument
   
myDwg.Regen acAllViewports
     ' Assuming your Excel data is in Sheet1, starting from cell A1
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        
        ' Assuming your data consists of X and Y coordinates in columns A and B
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
        ' Check if there are enough points to create a closed shape
        If lastRow < 2 Then
            MsgBox "Insufficient data to create a closed shape.", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        ' Get the vertices as a list
        Dim verticesList() As Double
        ReDim verticesList(0 To lastRow * 2 - 1)
        Dim i As Long
        Dim j As Long
        j = -1
        For i = 1 To lastRow
            j = j + 1
       verticesList(j) = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
       j = j + 1
       verticesList(j) = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
        Next i
        
        ' Create a polyline to represent the closed shape
        Dim polylineObj As IAcadLWPolyline
        Set polylineObj = myDwg.ModelSpace.AddLightWeightPolyline(verticesList)
        
        myDwg.Regen acAllViewports
        
        Dim offsetObj1 As Variant, offsetObj2 As Variant
        offsetObj1 = polylineObj.Offset(0.25)
        myDwg.Regen acAllViewports
        offsetObj2 = polylineObj.Offset(-0.125)         
        myDwg.Regen acAllViewports
        
        MsgBox "Closed shape created successfully!", vbInformation
    End Sub
```